# Verbs that "should" be used with に without に

Tags: nuances, particle-に, song-lyrics

> 当たり前だと思っていた明日が来ること"も"飽きていた

Does the meaning change without に? I would personally say 当たり前だと思っていた明日が来ること"にも"飽きていた, with に since I see 飽きる being used with に almost all the time. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like the quote is from [a song by 美波](https://www.kkbox.com/jp/ja/song/-pIkZo8RzoZVpz9Z4S).

Answer (score 1):

飽きた can take both に and は. E.g.,

- カレーに飽きた
- カレーは飽きた

mean mostly the same *I'm fed up with curry (e.g. due to having had it three days in a row)*. Possibly は adds contrastive nuance.

For your question, ことも is a version where も replaced は, and ことにも is a version where も is appended to ことに. も is the usual "too, also" particle, suggesting the speaker is bored with the expected things happening over and over again as well as other things.